# How do I fix the rigging of the eyelids?

Tags: mesh, rigging

So I have tried my hand at rigging my character but I'm having problems with the eyelid rig. Also, for some reason, sometimes the eyeballs pop out from the mesh when moving the bone. The rest of the rig works as intended more or less.  Could anyone take a look at the file I've included and see where I went wrong? I'm a rigging beginner in Blender and I'm sure this would be an easy fix for more experienced riggers. If anyone can help me fix it, I'd be really thankful as well. I'll be sure to study how the rig is fixed. ;w; Other than that, that's the only issue I have for now. [image]

Comment: for the eyelids I guess you need to extend a bit the weight of each bone. For the eyes, when does the pop out happen?

Comment: I think it may have been a bug when I tried moving the eye tracker bone. I would have to manually move it back into the eye socket.